# How to connect liquidtite to schedule 80 (or 40) pvc conduit?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, conduit, pvc

I'm running 3/4" Schedule 80 PVC conduit above ground for some backyard electrical.  There is a section where I need to go up a retaining wall to a receptacle box, and then back down to continue the run.

It's complicated to do straight runs here and I really think the best way for me to do this is to use flexible liquid-tight conduit at the receptacle box, but I can't figure out how to connect the straight sch 80 PVC pipe with the flexible liquidtight conduit.   All the connectors I'm finding online show a compression bushing for the liquidtight and external threads with locknut for outlet box (which I can use for the box).  But I'm looking to do conduit<->conduit.

Addendum: The conduit body + liquidtight coupler looks like it would solve my issue? (at minute 3:00) https://youtu.be/QcxWw_M6uVE?t=180

Comment: If I follow what you want to do you will probably need a threaded coupling to screw the connector in.

Comment: Why restrict yourself to straight runs? PVC can be heat bent (or you can buy sweeps pre-made.) Liquidtight is extremely expensive and possibly the worst conduit I've ever met for pulling through.

Comment: @EdBeal your comment improved my web search and I found this https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/435-007-3-4-schedule-40-pvc-female-adapter.html

Comment: @dabi -- the link you found is to the plumbing flavor; the *electrical* version of that is a thing, but may or may not be compatible with the male threads on LFNC connectors

Comment: The male thread on the lfnc is a standard pipe thread but if a inspector sees white not grey he will probably flag it.

Comment: ok thanks i'll keep looking

Answer (score 3):

Don't use flexible conduit for your application.

PVC is very easy to bend.  I use an electric heat gun like the kind you use for stripping paint.  The great thing about bending it is those bends remain water-tight and save you money on couplers.

If you decide to do a conduit-coupler-conduit connection you don't need a threaded connection with gaskets.  You need a PVC coupling.  You can connect them together by PVC-welding (it's like gluing), the same way PVC plumbing pipes are connected.  Notice the small amount of goo that dropped out of the connection when I welded this PVC conduit to the fitting for the box it goes into.  Check YouTube for videos on how to do this; it's really easy.  Don't get the stuff on your hands (that's why I'm wearing a latex glove in the photo) and don't inhale it.

[image: tools I used to bend PVC conduit]

[image: conduit PVC-welded to outlet box]

[image: picture showing pvc conduits coupled together]

Comment: Note that LFNC is *NOT* rated for use with PVC couplers!